# Why is Twig converting my "false" string to true with boolval?

Tags: twig

```
{% set var = "false" %}
{{ dump(var|boolval) }}
Output: true
```

Why?

Why is this `true` and not `false`

Comment: Because it's uses PHP's `boolval` function - [demo](https://ideone.com/x53hHg)

Comment: @demo so what would be a good way to convert it to false?

Comment: This [function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.boolval.php#116547) seems to do what you want